# How to keep my button's position and size on my image when changing screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the button that is on top of my image to stay in it's position when changing screen sizes. 
[Here is an image of how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GabgA.jpg)

```css
.titlecon {
  padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-img-1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.explore-store {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 15%;
  top: 40%;
  margin-right: 3.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid titlecon">
  <img src="images/Home_img.jpg" class="img-fluid home-img-1" alt="title_img">
  <a class="explore-store btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="products.html">Explore Store</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code so we have the full look in the screenshot available as a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is simple. Where do you want to keep the button steady ? If you want to keep it stable within the image, you can create a container covering the image and use "position:relative" for that container. So even if the picture gets smaller, the limits of the button will always be the size of the container.

```css
.titlecon {
  padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.home-img-1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.explore-store {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 5%;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid titlecon">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/amazon-rivet-furniture-1533048038.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.502xh;0,0.423xh&resize=1200:*" class="img-fluid home-img-1" alt="title_img">
    <a class="explore-store btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="products.html">Explore Store</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Elca Polydorou, this is a proper solution. Never, I mean, NOT EVER, use 'fixed units' (like in the other answer) to position an element when you want to create a responsive document as **'fixed' <> 'responsive'**. Read: [MDN: <length>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for some background on units.

Answer (score 0):

Try using translate instead of top and right.  Also, set your container to `display:flex;`  Look here. You can play with the window size here: https://jsfiddle.net/7nh6xyds/

```css
.titlecon {
  padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}


.home-img-1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.explore-store {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(300px, 200px);
  margin-right: 3.5%;
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid titlecon">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" class="img-fluid home-img-1" alt="title_img">
      <a class="explore-store btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="products.html">Explore Store</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Run the snippet, resize the browser window and you will see this solution fail... (jsFiddle fails too, I might add)